# Convert specific date format to Epoch in linux

Tags: linux, date, command-line, epoch

I need to convert this date format to epoch : 03/Apr/2016 14:22:59
the command

```
date -d "03/Apr/2016 14:22:59" +"%s"
```

will return :

```
date: invalid date â€˜03/Apr/2016 14:22:59
```

Anyone can help me format it in a way it become recognizable by date -d ?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perl to the rescue:

```
perl -MTime::Piece -e 'print Time::Piece
                             ->strptime("03/Apr/2016 14:22:59", "%d/%b/%Y %H:%M:%S")
                             ->epoch'
```

Answer (score 2):

Info page for date input formats can be shown with following command:

```
info date "Date input formats"
```

Unfortunately your date format is not supported by `date`. You can however convert your string into format that is supported for example like this:

```
date -d "$(echo '03/Apr/2016 14:22:59' | tr -s "/" "-")" +"%s"
```

To provide information about which kind of input strings can be used for `date` command I will write here a short summary:

#### Show date from epoch

```
date -d "@1513936964"
```

#### Words like today, tomorrow, month names (January), AM/PM, time zone names are supported

```
date -d "tomorrow 10:00:30PM"
date -d "03 April 2016 14:22:59"
```

#### Calendar formats

```
date -d "04/03/2016 14:22:59"
date -d "03-Apr-2016 14:22:59"
date -d "2016-04-03 14:22:59.00"
```

#### Timezones

```
date -d "PDT now"
```

#### Which day was Christmas last year?

```
date -d "$(date -d "2017-12-24") -1 year" +"%A"
```

Answer (score 1):

Using Python:

```
python -c 'from time import strftime, strptime;print strftime("%s", strptime("03/Apr/2016 14:22:59", "%d/%b/%Y %H:%M:%S"))'
```